# Multiple Selection and clip raster by mask in QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing, gdalwarp, extract-by-mask

I am doing raster by mask on multiple polygons. Selection on the basis of "CONTCD='AFR'" is running fine. Second selection and looping to for mask is only showing all.

```
layer=QgsVectorLayer("C:/output/b1.shp","b1", "ogr")  
raster = "C:/output/raster.tif" 
output="C:/output/
layer.selectByExpression("CONTCD='AFR'")
countryname=[]
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feat in selection:
    # print an attribute
    countryname.append(feat['ROMNAM'])
    
layer.removeSelection()

for i in countryname:
    # print an attribute
   layer.selectByExpression("ROMNAM"  +'='+ i)
   
   selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
  
   result= gdal.Warp(output + i+".tiff",raster,cutlineDSName=layer)
   layer.removeSelection()`
```

Comment: Your issue is in `gdal.Warp(output + i+".tiff",raster,cutlineDSName=layer)`. The part `cutlineDSName=layer` will never work: layer is a `QgsvectorLayer` and `gdal.Warp` does not know about this type of object. You are already lucky it does not throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to go through QGIS selection. You can go the "SQL way". There is not dependencies to QGIS: you can run it in the PyQGIS console but throught also Python script outside QGIS if GDAL Python installed

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

output_directory = '/tmp/'
input_raster = 'OB_50M/OB_50M.tif'
input_vector = 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp'
ds_vector = gdal.OpenEx(input_vector)
# Get a subset, similar to your first selection
result_vector_query = ds_vector.ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM ne_10m_admin_0_countries WHERE CONTINENT = 'Africa'")

file_prefix = 'whatever_'
# Loop and with cutlineSQL keep the WHERE condition and add your second condition
# Similar to your second selection (in fact, a selection based on a subset)
for i, feature in enumerate(result_vector_query):
    escaped_name = feature.GetField('NAME').replace("'", "\\'")
    print(escaped_name)
    result= gdal.Warp(
        output_directory + file_prefix + str(i) + ".tiff",
        input_raster,
        cutlineDSName=input_vector,
        cutlineSQL=f"SELECT * FROM ne_10m_admin_0_countries WHERE CONTINENT = 'Africa' AND NAME = '{escaped_name}'"
    )
```

PS: Datasets can be download on [NaturalEarthData website](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) to reproduce

Comment: Thank you @ThomasG77.That what i actually want.